# DataContext - LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio

I deleted a column from a my ms sql database but my web app is still recognizing it. I believe I need to regenerate my datacontext since I'm using LINQ but I can't find a way to do so in Visual Studio 2012.

Can anyone assist me?

Thank you.

Comment: Does your project contain a .dbml file for the context you need to change? Opening that in the editor should allow you to remove the column from the table, then rebuild.

Comment: Thank you. This was a simple and straightforward answer.

Comment: No trouble - I'll add it as an answer below, since it seems to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

Open datacontext model and right click on the entity (Table) and click update.

If it doesn't work then you need to regenerate the datacontext  or need to delete the column manually from the model.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a .dbml file in your project, then it will need to be edited to change the `DataContext` subclass responsible for allowing LINQ to SQL to communicate with your database. Open it in the editor to see a diagram of the tables in the `DataContext`. Right-click the column that has been removed, then click "delete" - this will remove all reference to the column.The project will need to be rebuilt once this is done.